# Documents to import a PC from Ukraine to the US for personal use

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, import-taxes

I want to import my PC from Ukraine to the US. I'm a student here on a F-1 visa. It is around 3-4 years old, and the total cost of all components (used) is around $1000 (+- $100). I want it to get send over a mail service, and I was wondering if I need to fill out any forms to make the process as easy and fast as possible. I do not plan to leave/sell it in the US.

Comment: A note: "personal use" is not much relevant, you still need to pay import taxes. There are exceptions when moving (but maybe it is not worth for just a package, but if you are moving other stuffs..). 1000$ for a 3-4 old computer seems quite a lot.

Comment: It was a high end computer at a time. Could you point me to a direction where to look for documents to fill out/duties I need to pay?

Comment: How do you want to send it? Check online on post office website (country of origin) or on courier website. But to send document, it is mandatory to do a uniformed custom declaration, for all parcels. So you will find in websites on your country of origin. In short: number of items, short description (usually in English), and estimate value. Sometime price of sending item is added, but this will be done by post office.courier.

Comment: My dad will send it, and he wants to use Meest Express (meest.us). It's basically a service to send packages to/from the US. I tried looking for information on their website, but the section with "Send parcels from Ukraine to the US" does not load.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a travel question, but a question about export and import. It might be a question to ask on [expatriates.se], but even there it might be off-topic.

Comment: How to close it?

Comment: You don't do that, other users vote. If enough users vote to close, the system will close the question. See: https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions If you wish, you can also delete the question, using the "delete" button below the question's text.

Comment: The webpage says “ If the value of cargo is more than $800 or more than 30 kg, the recipient must fill out form Power of Attorney (POA) and provide a copy of IRS or SS proof.” if it is less than 800.no taxes/duty. Maybe you can split the shipment or buy some part of it in the US to avoid the hassles.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany What webpage?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica meest.us as mentioned in a comment above. This is also true when sending items < $800 USD into the US from Canada, it's an informal entry by Canada Customs terminology.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany How is meest.us relevant? It ships within its east European sphere, and from the US...but not _to_ the US.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Services->Delivery from Ukraine to USA. ?? Unless they have this geo-blocked you should see it.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I don't see it. My wife's Rule of Life #4 is "Some things cannot be understood." Shrug. I'll just sit here and watch.